# Не проходит генерация (python)

Tags: python

```
#generate password
import string
def random_choice():
    gp = ''
    for x in range(8):
        gp += randome.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits+ string.ascii.punctuation)
    return gp
print(random_choice())
```

подскажите что нужно в принт вставить, чтоб началась генерация паролей
при таком варианте пишет error

```
gp += randome.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits+ string.ascii.punctuation)
```

> NameError: name 'randome' is not defined

Comment: Вы опечатались. Вам нужно написать `import random`, а потом использовать `random.choice`.

Comment: Стоит заметить, что использование стандартного random в чистом виде обычно считают не очень безопасным для генерации паролей и прочих важных ключей

Answer (score 4):

Вам необходимо импортировать модуль `random` ну и можно немного упростить:

```
import string
import random

def token(n):
    t = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for i in range(n))
    return t

print(token(16))
```

Функцию вызывайте с числовым парамтром - длина Вашего пароля

Answer (score 4):

В Python 3.6 появился новый встроенный модуль [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/secrets.html):

> The secrets module is used for generating cryptographically strong
>   random numbers suitable for managing data such as passwords, account
>   authentication, security tokens, and related secrets.
>
> In particularly, secrets should be used in preference to the default
>   pseudo-random number generator in the random module, which is designed
>   for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography.

Пример:

```
import secrets
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(20))
```

Результат:

```
In [43]: print(password)
TKuNKcy8doUJKxF3eGit
```

Comment: выше писали по поводу безопасности. этот метод будет лучше?

Comment: @Nastya, да, его именно для этого и придумали. `In particularly, secrets should be used in preference to the default pseudo-random number generator in the random module, which is designed for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography.`